# How to add Start of String to a value in a variable passed to RegExp object

Tags: javascript

This javascript code tries to check if a value in the variable `typedString` matches in the string in the variable `item` and returns boolean.  It is not returning any results unless I remove the `\\A` which I need to be the start of a word. How can it be fixed? Thanks

```
let typedString = 'man';  // looking for this 
let item = 'women/man'; // in this or 'he is a man'
let re = new RegExp("\\A" + typedString, 'g');
if (re.test(item)) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: what are valid inputs

Comment: Try `new RegExp('\\b' + typedString + '\\b', 'g');`

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/aqcLw3r1/)

Comment: @Tushar Yes. that fixed it. thx